# php command pointing to different version of php in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, path, lampp

when I run the php command in Ubuntu, it points to another version of php installed. I want php command to refer to my lampp installed version of php.
When I type where is PHP,  it gives me a list of all multiple strings, the first one being the version 7.x which i do not want. I need the third one which is the lampp installation version of php. How do I change the php path to the desired one (3rd string ie. '/opt/lampp/bin/php')

Comment: could you uninstall the php versions you dont want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an alias. To create an alias permanently, add the alias to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

1. At the command prompt, type `vi ~/.bashrc`
2. Press `SHIFT+G` keys to go to the bottom of the file
3. Press `o` key to insert new line.
4. Enter `alias php=/opt/lampp/bin/php`
5. Press `Esc` key to exist insert mode.
6. Press `:wq` keys to save and quit `vi`
7. Run `. ~/.bashrc` to reprocess your `~/.bashrc` file and to have the alias take effect.

Now, when you execute `php` it will run `/opt/lampp/bin/php` which is what you want.

Comment: Hey thanks @Konstantin . This Solved the issue I was facing.